# How To Get The Sum of Two Times Using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to add two times like `time1 = '00:05'` and `time2 = '10:00'`. I want the result like the following after sum: `result='10:05'`. I used moment for that, this is what I used:

```js
 let x = moment.duration(moment(this.time1, "hh:mm A").add(moment(this.time2, "hh:mm A")));
 let result = moment.utc(x.asMilliseconds()).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

but I got nothing, how can I do it?

Comment: `'00:05 PM'` is a time, not a duration; it means five minutes past midnight, not just five minutes. And ask one question at a time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok what u recommend to do it. what should i use

Comment: I recommend you start by using a coherent representation of time. Without understanding why your inputs and expected outputs are what they are, it’s hard to say what you should do. Adding times makes no sense, which is why datetime libraries include duration/time delta types.

Comment: I suggest you start by learning about the difference between a "time" and a "duration".

Answer (score 2):

You can't add time this way with moment because you are asking it to add two times, not a time plus a duration. If you want to add ten minutes, use the `add()` function with a duration.

```
moment(this.time2, "hh:mm A").add(10, 'minutes')
```

More here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

It's not really clear in your question what `00:05 PM` means. That doesn't look like a valid time. Moment will interpret it as 12:05pm, but it looks like you want to interpret it as 5 minutes. (That's the only way you get 10:05 as an answer). You can do this with moment if you don't include the `PM` part of the string.

```
moment.duration('00:05')
```

Is a duration of five minutes. You *can* add this to your time with:

```
moment('10:00 PM', '"hh:mm A"').add(moment.duration('00:05'))
// 22:05:00
```

Adding two periods works but it is currently not obvious in moment, how to format it like you want. Until they add `format()` to durations this will have to do:

```
 var d = moment.duration('03:10:10').add(moment.duration('01:20:30'))
 moment.utc(d.as('milliseconds')).format("HH:mm:ss")
// '04:30:40'
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to add 10 min i want to add two diff times because they will be various and i don't  know the time but what i'm sure of that the format of time is `hh:mm A`

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed What does it mean to add two times? What is 11:20pm + 3:00pm? Maybe you want to add a time to the difference from midnight of another time?

Comment: what i mean i want to write a code which add times which will be one of the following

`3:20:00 PM + 00:10:30 PM`
Or
`3:20:00 AM + 00:10:30 PM`
is there is any way that do that ?

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed I don't know what `00:10:30 PM` means. PM times start at 12:00pm and end at 11:59pm. There is no `00:10:30 pm` If you pass this to moment, it will return 12:10pm. Do you want to add 12 hours and 10 minutes to your time?

Comment: Oh So sorry my mistake i onlnly want to add the period like this
`01:20:30` which means 1 hour ,20 min and 30 seconds to `03:10:10` to get the expected result as `04:30:40` sorry for my mistake

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed that's much easier. See the last part of my answer. You can define the period with `moment.duration('1:20:30')` and use `moment.add()`.

Comment: thanks but can give me an example for add the previous 2 periods from my last comment starting from converting them to period till the result because i don't understand momentjs

Answer (score 2):

> See Example For Add & Diff using moment.js .. cheers

```
   // addTimes(["01:00", "00:30", "00:50"]) ---- 02:20

   addTimes(times) {
    let duration = 0;
    times.forEach(time => {
      duration = duration + moment.duration(time).as('milliseconds')
    });
    return  moment.utc(duration).format("HH:mm")
   }

   // subtractTimes(["05:00", "00:30", "00:20"]) --- 04:10


   subtractTimes(times) {
    let totalDiff = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < times.length; i++) {
      let duration = moment.duration(times[i]).as('milliseconds')
      if (i == 0) {
        totalDiff = duration
      }
      if (i > 0) {
        totalDiff = totalDiff - duration
      }
    }
    return moment.utc(totalDiff).format("HH:mm")
  }
```

Comment: very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addTwoHours(firstTime = "20:40", secondTime = "18:40") {
  firstTime = firstTime.split(':');
  secondTime = secondTime.split(':');
  const now = moment();
  const expiration = moment().add({ hour: firstTime[0], minute: firstTime[1] }).add({ hour: secondTime[0], minute: secondTime[1] });
  const diff = expiration.diff(now);
  const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

  return {
    "years": diffDuration.years(),
    "months": diffDuration.months(),
    "days": diffDuration.days(),
    "hours": diffDuration.hours(),
    "minutes": diffDuration.minutes(),
    "yourAnswer" : `${expiration.diff(now, 'hours')}:${diffDuration.minutes()}`
  }
}

console.log(addTwoHours());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```